# jquery ajax call for deleting a row

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I delete a row by just passing the `id` using a jquery ajax call on a link button?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".remove_row").click(function (event){ 
        event.preventDefault();        
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: url, 
            success: function() { return false; }, 
            error: function(){ alert('An error.'); } 
        }); 
        return false;
    ); 
});
```

do I need to mention the dataType: and write  success function .. when I want to just delete the row?

Comment: do you receive the call in your page? the page that is explicit in the `url` variable? if yes, what is really your problem?

Comment: What is `.remove_row`? How does your table look like? You kind of overwrite the normal function of your remove button with this ajax call. So you can't trigger the normal remove anymore. To help you we need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not clear, assuming these possible cases:

1. you want to remove any element on your page

   ```
   $('#Elementid').remove();
   ```
2. you want to remove a row from a databound list or table i.e. you want to remove row from your database:

   in this case you will need to call server side static method and pass the id of the row to be deleted which can be done as shown below:

   ```
   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                data: "{'id':value}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d); 
                }
   });
   ```

and your ServerSideMethod on WebForm1.aspx should be like this:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string ServerSideMethod(int id)
  {
      string query ="delete from table where id="+id;
      //rest of the dml operation
      return "Message from server."; 
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, the question was not clear. I was trying to remove a <dd> in a loop. ajax call was deleting the id from the database but the row wasn't getting deleted. So what i did was gave the dd an id, recieved the id in response and deleted the specific <dd> row dynamically.                                                                                                                            Thanks for all your responses.

Answer (score 0):

To delete any HTML element use:

```
$('#row_id').remove();
```

This may not be a complete solution but I think the question is not complete, so this is the best I can do.